# Problem with COPY FROM with PHP in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, csv

I have some big .csv files and I am trying to put it into database. I am using this construction:

```
COPY table_name(column1, column2, column..., columnN) FROM stdin;
column1 column2 column... column N
column1 column2 column... column N
column1 column2 column... column N
column1 column2 column... column N
\.
```

But after use \i function in CLI I got that:

```
ERROR:  end-of-copy marker corrupt
```

This is not a problem with end marker, but with encoding. If I open this file in VIM and will save it again, everything is OK, but without this operations I got this error all the time. What can I do in PHP (with PHP I create those files) to fix that? If this is for sure problem with encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there also a newline after the `\.` ? Check the example in the PHP-manual for [pg_put_line()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php) as well and take notice of the `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy solution for this, you only need to press "`Enter`" after "`\.`" and then save your file and try again, it will resolve your issue.